# How to increase the image size in Universal image loader?

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader

Using an **Universal Image loader** i'm trying to increase the size of the image which i got from JSON url and i tried all possible methods available in valuable stackoverflow but didn't get the right solution to increase the image size so here i am posting my code and correct me by giving your suggestions.Thanks in advance

```
public ImageSlideAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<Product> products,
        HomeFragment homeFragment) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.homeFragment = homeFragment;
    this.products = products;
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)   .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
           .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).cacheInMemory() .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
            .cacheOnDisc().build();

    imageListener = new ImageDisplayListener();
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific size you want an image to be?

Comment: till now there  is no specific size for that image just i need to increase and decrease the size that's it

Comment: Are you referring to zooming in and zooming out the image?